# How to parse query with '+' sign ?

Tags: http, express, httpwebrequest

I'm building express server replica for a school project.

And I need to parse http request like this for example :

```
GET /request/test/query?q=omer+ornan HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
```

Sould my `req.query` property be `{"q":"omer+ornan"}`  or `{"q":"omer ornan"}`
or maybe space sign sould be translated into something else ? 
I cant find any referense in https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use plain text.  The system will url encode it, adding the plus sign.